# aiogram3.3.0 does not send payment send_invoice

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

(Python 3.11, Aiogram 3.3.0)

I want to add a subscription payment to the bot… I looked at a few examples and documentation, I don’t see any errors.

When I write to the bot /payment, I only get a message, but on send_invoice() there is complete silence, no errors or payments…

```
/
|- handlers
|  |- bot_message.py
|- main.py
```

```py
# bot_messages.py

from aiogram import Router,F,Bot
from aiogram.types import (
    Message,
    ContentType,
    LabeledPrice,
    PreCheckoutQuery
)
from aiogram.filters import (
    Command
)

@router.message(Command(commands="payment"))
async def pay(message:Message,bot=Bot):
    print("pay send")

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Your order payment") # get only this message

    await bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id= message.chat.id,
        title="title",
        description="desc_test",
        payload=f'test-invoice-payload',
        provider_token='TEST_TOKEN',
        currency='USD',
        prices=[
            LabeledPrice(
                label='Sub month',
                amount=299*100
            )
        ],
        max_tip_amount=100*100,
        suggested_tip_amounts=[100*100,300*100],
        start_parameter=f'testpaymentbot',
        provider_data=None,
        need_email=True,
        need_phone_number=True,
        need_name=True,
        need_shipping_address=False,
        send_phone_number_to_provider=False,
        send_email_to_provider=False,
        is_flexible=False,
        disable_notification=False,
        protect_content=True,
        reply_to_message_id=None,
        allow_sending_without_reply=True,
        reply_markup=None,
        request_timeout=30
    )


@router.pre_checkout_query()
async def process_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query: PreCheckoutQuery, bot: Bot):

    if pre_checkout_query.invoice_payload != "test_payload":
        await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=False, error_message="errors gere...")
    else:
        await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)

@router.message(F.content_type == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def succesfull_payment(message: Message):
    print("succesfull_payment activate")
    msg = f"Thank you for sub {message.successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency}!"
    await message.answer(msg)
```

```py
# main.py
from handlers import bot_messages
async def main() -> None:
    try:
        bot = Bot(token=f"{conf.bot_token}",parse_mode="HTML")
        dp = Dispatcher()
        dp.include_routers(
            bot_messages.router
        )
        logger_bot.info("Bot initialization succesful!")
    except (Exception,AiogramError) as _ex:
        logger_bot.critical(f"Can't initilize bot! Error: {_ex}")
    try:
        await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
        logger_bot.info(f"Bot start succesful! {bot.id}|{bot.get_my_name}")
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    except (Exception,AiogramError) as _ex:
        logger_bot.critical(f"Can't start bot! Error: {_ex}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Help me figure out why the payment is not sent… I’ve been struggling for a week…

[image]

just text message...

- I tried different providers (PayMaster and other) the payment is not sent and there are no errors (maybe there are, but I literally don’t see what the error is).
- try use create_invoice_link()
- try multiply amount by 100